# Find $n, m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2\alpha m +2(3-\alpha)n=nm$ for some $\alpha\in\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In my research I need to find $n, m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n,m\geq 3$ and  $2\alpha m +2(3-\alpha)n=nm$ for some $\alpha\in\{1, 2, 3\}$. I know that $(n, m)\in \{(3, 12), (4, 8), (5, 10)\}$. But, I need to know how obtain them.

By $2\alpha m +2(3-\alpha)n=nm$ for some $\alpha\in\{1,2,3\}$, clearly $nm$ is even number. If $m>n$, then $n(m-6)=2\alpha m-2\alpha n$, this implies that $m>6$, ...

Is there a method to solve the equation $2\alpha m +2(3-\alpha)n=nm$ for some $\alpha\in\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $n, m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n, m\geq 3$?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: In the header you said $\alpha\in \mathbb N$ and in the main text you're saying $\alpha\in\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: @PNDas Thanks, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$nm = un+vm$
then
$uv
=nm-un-vm+uv
=(n-v)(m-u)
$.

If $uv=0$
there are 3 cases.

If $u=v=0$
then $nm=0$
so $n=0$ or $m=0$
or both.

If
$u=0, v\ne 0$
then $nm=vm$
so $m=0, n=$anything
or $n=v, m=$anything non-zero.

If $u\ne 0, v=0$
then
$nm=un$
so
$n=0, m=$anything
or $m=u, v=$anything non-zero.

If $uv \ne 0$
then
for each factorization
$uv=rs$,
want
$n-v=r, m-u=s$
or
$n=v+r, m=u+s$.

Solutions to this
are always
$(r, s)
=(1, uv), (u, v), (v, u), (uv, 1)
$
so
$(n, m)
=(v+1, u+uv), (2v, 2u), (u+v, u+v),
(v+uv, u+1)
$.

There may be others.

Writing $a$ for $\alpha$,
letting
$u=2(3-a)$
and
$v=2a
$,
so
$uv=4a(3-a)
$.

For $a=(1, 2, 3)
$,
this is
$4a(3-a)
=(8, 8, 0)
$.

if $uv=0$,
$a=3$
so
$u=0, v=6$
so $m=0, n=$anything
or $n=6, m=$ anything non-zero.

Otherwise
$uv=8$
so the factorizations are
$(r, s)
=(1, 8), (2, 4), (4, 2), 
(8, 1)
$
so the solutions are,
for $a=1, 2)$
$(n, m)
=(2a+1, 2(3-a)+8),
(2a+2, 2(3-a)+4),
(2a+4, 2(3-a)+2),
(2a+8, 2(3-a)+1)
$.

For $a=1$,
$2a=2, 2(3-a)=4$
so these are
$(n, m)
=(3, 12),
(4, 8),
(8, 6),
(10, 5)
$.

For $a=2$,
$2a=4, 2(3-a)=2$
so these are
$(n, m)
=(5, 10),
(6, 6),
(8, 4),
(12, 3)
$.

Comment: Thanks, I think $(8, 6)$ must be replaced by $(6, 6)$

Answer (score 1):

**Case $\alpha=1$:**

$2m+4n=mn\iff\dfrac{2}{n}+\dfrac{4}{m}=1\iff\dfrac{4}{m}=\dfrac{n-2}{n}$.

Now, since $\dfrac{n-2}{n}$ has to be positive, $n$ has to be greater than $2$. Furthermore, as $n$ increases, the value of $\dfrac{n-2}{n}$ increases. Therefore, the minimum value of $\dfrac{n-2}{n}$ is $\dfrac{3-2}{3}=\dfrac{1}{3}$. There are only finitely many solutions to $\dfrac{4}{m}\geq\dfrac{1}{3}$. For each of the $12$ possible values of $m$, solve for $n$.

$\\$

The other cases are not that different.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If $\alpha=1$, then $2m+4n=mn$.

While  $m>n$, then $6n<mn<6m$ or ($6<m$ and $n<6$).

While $n\ge3$, then $n\in\{3,4,5\}$.

By checking those potential candidates for $n$, we have:

{$n=3$ and $m=12$} and {$n=4$ and $m=8$}.

(2) If $\alpha=2$ and $m>n$, then $6n<4m+2n=mn<6m$.

Again similarly $n\in\{3,4,5\}$, and we have:

{$n=5$ and $m=10$}.

(3) If $\alpha=3$, then:

$n=6$ for any $m\ge3$.